# Can't move vertices down

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm following the donut series on youtube and I have a problem when I want to move vertices of icing down to look more like an icing. the problem is that when I hit g I can move them down but while holding alt + s, something weird happens and it seems that vertices are going inward the donut rather than outward.
the first picture, is while pressing alt + s and second one shows when I press g.
I apologize for my poor level of English. I hope you get what I mean
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you pressing Alt S? Alt S is for Shrink/Fatten, not sure it's what you want here. Also, it doesn't look like you've enabled the Snap option, you can activate it with the Ctrl key but anyway, you need to choose the Snap to Face if you want the vertex to snap to the donut face. At last, the vertices may still go into the donut because it has a Subdivision Surface modifier and it makes the surface look round